# How to make Rigidbody.AddForce less delayed in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, platformer, rigidbody

I'm trying to make it so that when the player in my game moves left or right, he lightly jumps from his current position to his new position. The way I have it set up now, the jump occurs once he has arrived at his new position. What can I do to make it so that the jump happens sooner so that it appears that he jumps to his new position? Here is the code I have that controls that part of his movement:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x > minXPos)
    {
        targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x - xIncrement, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForceTwo, ForceMode.Impulse);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(targetPos, transform.position, speed);
        isHorizontalingLeft = true;
    }
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x < maxXPos)
    {
        targetPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + xIncrement, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForceTwo, ForceMode.Impulse);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(targetPos, transform.position, speed);
        isHorizontalingRight = true;
    }
```

Here is a video showing what is happening (sorry it's blurry):
https://youtu.be/rPewtb8QywE

Comment: You should not mix rigidbody and non-rigidbody movement the way you have here. If you're moving an object with physics, you should move it *solely* with physics, and treat the transform as read-only. Mixing the two leads to bugs and undesired behaviour.

Comment: @DMGregory Always good advice, but I don't think that's the problem here. In the video it looks like the character is teleporting instead of moving, probably because he forgot `Time.deltaTime` and the speed is too high. It would probably be a nightmare to handle horizontal movement with forces in this type of game, though `RigidBody.MovePosition()` is still better than transform.position

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from a video when you're applying input, but it looks to me like your problem is not that the jump is delayed, but rather that your character teleports instantly instead of moving over a period of time.

Your code moves the player like this:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(targetPos, transform.position, speed);
```

I am assuming your code takes place in an `Update()` function. You are not accounting for `Time.deltaTime` here, so your character may be moving 60x faster than you expect. Normally your speed should be in units per second and you should multiply speed by `Time.deltaTime` like this:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(targetPos, transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

This way your movement speed is consistent regardless of framerate. For example, if the speed is 10 and a frame lasts 1/60th of a second, the actual distance moved in one frame would be `10 * (1 / 60)` = `.16667`. If the game stuttered during the next frame and the frame lasted 2/60ths of a second, the distance moved for that frame would be `10 * (2 / 60)` = `.333333`